# How to send a message from a non ROS node to a ROS node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible to have a program on a remote device which doesn't have ROS installed that sends messages to a ROS node on another device (which has ROS)?

I was thinking to start small and have a small c program that sends an int via a udp channel, but I'm not sure how this is going to be received, or published to a topic. Any guideline on how you would go about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225438/how-to-send-a-message-from-a-non-ros-node-to-a-ros-node/) by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2016-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably shouldn't try to publish directly to a ROS topic from a non-ROS system (this would effectively mean re-implementing the ROS libraries for some other platform, which probably isn't what you want to do).

Instead, the common pattern here is to write a gateway node which communicates over standard TCP or UDP on one side, and publishes ROS messages, and to run this node on your ROS system.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-31**:
To add to this: alternatively (depending on the amount of integration desired), you could use something like [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) or perhaps [cROS](https://github.com/it-robotics/cros).

**Comment by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) on 2016-01-31**:
Thank you for your tips!! I will look into them:)